# How to select a column stored as hash values in active record where method?

Tags: activerecord

I have table column called data and the values are stored as :date1 : 04/05/2015, :date2 : 05/12/2015.

I got one active record relation class and in the where method i want to take the value of data[:date1], data[:date2] like that?

How to do it? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific and show your query and the results it's returning? 

Is the ```data``` field storing the hashes in an array? i.e. ```[data[:date1], data[:date2]]```

Are the results actually a hash if you call .class on it?

You need to be more specific if you want help :)

Comment: Results are in ActiveRecord::Relation class. Yes i have data field stored in the hashes, like :date1: 03/30/2015, :date_2: 03/30/2015 and :date_3: 03/30/2015